# Java - copying odd elements from array to another

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

```
    this.blockHeights = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 };

    int x = blockHeights.length/2;

    int leftSource[] = new int[x];
    System.out.println(x);
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if ((blockHeights[i]%2 == 0) || (i == 0)) //odd-elements
        {
            leftSource[i] = blockHeights[i];
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < leftSource.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(leftSource[i]);
    }
```

The output is 1, 2, 0, 0. Whereas my goal is to print out 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th element from array blockHeights and put it in new array leftSource.

Comment: You check for the wrong oddness: You say you want to *print out 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th element from array*, so you should check whether the *index* is odd. What you check with `(blockHeights[i]%2 == 0)`, though, is whether the *value* is odd.

Comment: You just reward the guy who answered last, and may inspire his answer from other, great ^^ from the 5 answers he is the last^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the odd index members to a new array (regardless of their value), like you said - 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th - then try this:

```
this.blockHeights = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 };

    int x = blockHeights.length/2;

    int leftSource[] = new int[x];
    System.out.println(x);
    //go over the larger array and skip by 2
    for (int i = 0; i < blockHeights.length; i=i+2)
    {  
       leftSource[i/2] = blockHeights[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < leftSource.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(leftSource[i]);
    }
```

Comment: @RamishKhan please look who answered in first please, and who inspire his answer from the other, please ^^

Comment: @RamishKhan, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

add elements you get with `i%2 != 0` also the new Array should only have the half size of the original Array. Also you Loop must run until the end of the first Array and not only to the half.

Try the following code.

```
this.blockHeights = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 };

int x = blockHeights.length/2;

int leftSource[] = new int[x];
System.out.println(x);
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <  blockHeights.length; i++) //changed this line
{
    if (i%2 != 0) //odd-elements //changed this line
    {
        leftSource[j] = blockHeights[i]; //changed this line
        j++;//changed this line
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < leftSource.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(leftSource[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so your code prints 0201 instead of 1122 which are "1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th element" asked by Ramish Khan ;)

Comment: @azro That can not be. Where should the Zero comes from?

Comment: I'll let you try ;) Because of empty places ;) because you use same index for both ;) look my answer above

Comment: @azro Thanks for ponting that out. I have changed my code

Comment: your code seems a bit complicated, no need of 2 variables and a `if` ;)

Comment: @maybe complicated, but understandable

Answer (score 0):

In `int x = blockHeights.length / 2;` you set `x` to half of `blockHeights` length, so in the first `for` loop you are iterating over the left half of the array. Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockHeights.length; i++)
```

You also need to check if `i` is odd or even, not the element in the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < lockHeights.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        leftSource[i / 2] = blockHeights[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have missing element, and blank in array / `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you'll get ;)

Comment: Everyone was wrong except me at begin, and now that I've correct you, we all have about the same thing ^^

Answer (score 0):

change

```
        if ((blockHeights[i]%2 == 0) || (i == 0)) //odd-elements
```

to

```
        if(i%2 != 0) //odd-elements
```

or you can change the for loop

```
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i+=2)
{
        leftSource[i] = blockHeights[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your look at the value of the element, to check if its odd but it's odd position that you want, so you need to store in folowwing places in leftSource but get value 1 over 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
         leftSource[i] = blockHeights[i * 2];
//1 1 2 2
```

A convenient method to print an array is : `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(leftSource));  //[1,1,2,2]`

---

If you do `for (int i = 0; i < x; i = i + 2)` you'll take the good values, but only 1st and 3rd and have empty places